# How to get "all" the weights in Keras?

Tags: keras, get, conv-neural-network, layer

I use "model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]" to get the weights in Keras, but it shows "..." if the total amount is over 1000. Does anyone know how to get "all" the weights in Keras without showing "..."?

Comment: The "..." is just a printing artifact from numpy, not a value stored in the weights.

Comment: Dr. Snoopy, do you know how to get each value of all weights in Keras?

Comment: You are already doing it, get_weights() on a layer or model, it is just a visualization problem, the weights are all in the returned list.

Comment: Dr. Snoopy could you please provide the code to overcome the visualization problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but I recently stumbled upon this problem too. I converted my numpy array to a list before printing it. In your case the following should work:

```
print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].tolist())
```